# Python: re.search malfunctioning

Tags: python

When attempting to run code using re.search I'm getting the following error: AttributeError: module 're' has no attribute 'search'.

```
#!/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3

import re

if __name__ == "__main__":
    list_of_strings = ["This is string 1",
                   "This is another string",
                   "Most material here",
                   "Let's give it enough to be interesting",
                   "1 last strings"
                   ]

    print ("\nSearch")
    for x in list_of_strings:
        find = re.search("string(.)", x)
        if find:
            print (x)
```

[image]

Comment: If you named a file `re.py`, name it something else.

Comment: I just renamed in b.py and I'm getting the same result.

Comment: Delete `re.pyc`.

Comment: That worked, thanks!